# Why does this dice rolling function output 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to complete [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/1j50e7/project_dice_rolling_simulator/) challenge but I've gotten stuck.

This is what I have so far. Except when I run it with args 4 and 6 it outputs random numbers.

```
import random

def roller(rolls, sides):
    i = 0
    while i != rolls:
        x = random.randint(1, sides)
        i += 1
        return x

    lst = range(1, sides)
    lst = [str(i) for i in lst]

    for elem in lst:
        return elem + ": " + str(x)

print(roller((int(input("# of rolls: "))) ,(int(input("# of sides: ")))))
```

Why in the same format as in the example? And why does it output only one value?

Comment: Because `return` exists the function and *returns* control to the caller

Comment: Your exiting your `while` loop as soon as the first random number is drawn.

Comment: `return` does exactly, what it says - it returns the value and terminates the execution of your function. [Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) might help you understand, what your script does

Comment: It would help tremendously if you told us what the actual output is that you are expecting. 'the output is not in the correct format' doesn't tell us much. Especially because the first `return` statement in your code is not the only problem you have.